# How can install Google Market to GoogleTV emulator?

Tags: google-tv

I read the following blogs to install android market to android emulators:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/10004/accessing-android-market-from-android-sdk
http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html

I followed the above instructions and tried to apply to Goolge TV emulator but it did not work. 
How can i install Android Market to Google TV emulator?

Answer (score 1):

The Android Market is not available for installation on any emulator. The Android Market is only available to licensees, for putting it on hardware that meets the compliance docs and tests.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but i used to know it. I would like to use other Google TV apps on Android Markets in emulator.